# How can I define Array.reduce method in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

I have a problem with the `reduce` method in TypeScript:

```
const items = {a: 10, b:20, c: 30}
const itemsTotal = Object.keys(items).reduce((accumulator: number, key: keyof typeof items ) => {
    return accumulator + items[key]
  }, 0)
```

I keep receiving the Typescript error:

> Argument of type '(accumulator: number, key: "a" | "b" | "c") => number' is not assignable to parameter of type '(previousValue: string, currentValue: string, currentIndex: number, array: string[]) => string'.
>
> ```
> Types of parameters 'accumulator' and 'previousValue' are incompatible.***
> ```

It seems that I need to define the type of the `reduce` method, but how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Object.keys` returns a `string[]`, so you can't apply a reducer function that expects a `keyof typeof items` to it.

You could use a type assertion, since you know it's valid:

```typescript
const items = {a: 10, b:20, c: 30};
const itemsTotal = Object.keys(items).reduce((accumulator, key) => {
    return accumulator + items[key as keyof typeof items];
}, 0);
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAllApgWwjAvDA3gQwFwwCMADADQwBGeATGTMAQMzEC+A3AFCiSwIoQAVEFBwAbDDADyFAFaJgUAHQBrRAE8IACj6oAlIoBOiACYBXYIk2acwYKeSnROKCAPlVa3RgB82DjACYIyhTAzAYGzsHJxcDGABqeCRUAG0PCLQPEAAzGCg1AAdEHKT+AF1OFnJiXTYgA)

...but you don't need the key anyway, just use `Object.values`:

```typescript
const items = {a: 10, b:20, c: 30};
const itemsTotal = Object.values(items).reduce((accumulator, value) => {
    return accumulator + value;
}, 0);
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAllApgWwjAvDA3gQwFwwCMADADQwBGeATGTMAQMzEC%20A3AFCiSwIoQAVEFBwAbDDADyFAFaJgUAHQA3MQFdEEABR9UASkUAnRABM1wRFq05gwNcjWicUEIfKrRGvRgB82DjCBMMZQaoZgMDZ2Dk4uhjAA1DAeGpws5MR6bEA)

(But frankly I'd just use [a simple loop](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAllApgWwjAvDA3gQwFwwCMADADQwBGeATGTMAQMzEC+A3AFAA2isCKEACogoOLhhjFOAMxAAnGAApQkWADcxAV0QwQ0mAHkKAK0TAoAOg1dtERf1QBKR9g4x38JKmGjxAakxrbU4WDiA).)

Comment: Thanks T.J. both of your answers solved my problem. Kudoz to you

Answer (score 1):

Define your items as a [Record](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeys-type) of `string` to `number`. It will be clear for the `reduce` method that the item is a `number`.

```
const items: Record<string, number> = {a: 10, b: 20, c: 30}

const itemsTotal = Object.keys(items).reduce((accumulator: number, key: string) => {
    return accumulator + items[key];
}, 0)
```

You can also skip the braces in the `reduce` body.

```
Object.keys(items).reduce((acc: number, key: string) => acc + items[key], 0)
```

Even more, you can skip the type designations in the `reduce` because your `items` are already defined as numbers in the `Record`.

```
Object.keys(items).reduce((acc, key) => acc + items[key], 0)
```

**Edit**

You can skip the accumulator initialization. `reduce` starts from the first item in such a case.

```
Object.values(items).reduce( (acc, item) => acc + item )
```

The **fastest solution** is with `for` `of` because there are no function calls:

```
let sum = 0
for (const item of Object.values(items)) {
   sum += item;
}
```

Comment: @Manzana, it is always a good idea to define your objects. Using `Record<string, number>` defines both the keys and the values.

Answer (score 1):

Not the cleanest solution but you can use this snippet:

```
const items = { a: 10, b: 20, c: 30 }
const itemsTotal = Object.keys(items).reduce((accumulator, key) => {
    return accumulator + items[key as keyof typeof items]
}, 0)
```

Key point is to cast `key` to  `keyof typeof items`

Comment: Great answer @Drag13, it solved my problem.